# Why does Typescript uses 'number' instead of int'?

Tags: typescript, architecture

I'm quite familiar with the framework, I love it since inception.

One thing that I haven't fully been able to grasp is why the Typing was sometimes off.

Specifically for this question, `number`, I'm not sure why the `int` wasn't used, at first I thought it might be the discrepancy of behavior between int32 / int16 / float etc.. But that doesn't make sense (to me) in transpilation.

So from the [lib](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7c47be76b05e08605a368984b8961b5f27a31c59/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L542) it needs to play nice with [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

My question is really about semantics, why was the decision made to use `number` and not `int` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that is what JavaScript uses.

## Example

```
console.log(typeof 123); // 'number'
```